# Opening fragment from another activity with additional information

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sliding

I have an `activity` (`activity A`) that has a few `sliding fragments`. From one of the fragments (`fragmentA`, part of activity A) I am opening another `activity` (`activity B`) when a `button is clicked` on that `fragment`. Another `fragment` (`fragment B`, part of `activity A`) in the sliding menu has an option to `add` or `delete` something from the `database` whose `buttons` are in the `action bar`. Now from `activity B`, I am trying to finalize `activity B` and open the `fragment B` and then automatically have the "`add` something `to database`" item clicked. Basically I am trying to `open a fragment from another activity`. I'm not sure how I can do this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get that

Comment: post some code is what I mean sorry

Comment: There is just too much code. I just needed an idea of how I could do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Activity B` where you want to move to `FragmentB` Of `ActivityA` write

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentB;  );
ft.commit();
```

Where  `R.id.content_frame` is layout id For your `Activity A`  and for doing `database`  with `button` in  `action bar` write code in `Activity A`  and `FragmentB` in `onCreateOptionsMenu` and in `FragmentB` write

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
                setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        }
```

Still You are not getting the solution than please post your code ..

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to have a global method for updating the DB. This way you can invoke it by clicking the ActionBarItems in your Activity A and by any time in your Activity B (or C,D...).

Another way would be to send a flag in your Intent you use to call A from B. Read the flag and if it fulfills your condition update your DB.

Also you could use startActivityForResult() and send a result from B to A which indicates that the DB should be updated.

As a hint: Don't burry functions which you have to call periodically in any App state. Make it more reachable.